How to fix Cannot use import statement outside a module error
I am working on a Chrome extension using Vite, React, and TypeScript. The extension includes a content script that I want to inject into active tabs. However, I am encountering the following error when the content script runs:
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot use import statement outside a module at content.js:1:1 
vite.config.ts

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'


// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: 'manifest.json',
          dest: ''
        }
      ]
    })
  ],
  build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        popup: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        background: resolve(__dirname, "src/background.ts"),
        content: resolve(__dirname, 'src/content.tsx'),
        chat: resolve(__dirname, 'src/chat/Chat.tsx')
      },
      output: {
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].[hash].js',
        assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  }
})



I ensured that my content script is bundled using Vite and checked that the content script is injected properly in the manifest.json
manifest.json

{
    "name": "My Extension",
    "description": "Extension",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "116",
    "action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/icon1.png",
      "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabCapture", "offscreen", "scripting"],
    "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }



Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75785671/error-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-while-testing-in-vite

Yes, my package.json include "type": "module" and I dont thinks other are related to my problem.

You need to configure your rollup/vite to produce a normal script, not a module, and make a separate build entry for the content script, so it doesn't try to use static imports, because those don't work a content script.

It appears that your project does not allow ES6+ imports. Try specifying "type": "module" in your package.json

I have included module in package.json

Maybe this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104433/how-to-import-es6-modules-in-content-script-for-chrome-extension
